# How many different arrangements are there of all letters in "balloon" if either all the l's or all the o's are adjacent, but not both?

Tags: combinatorics

How many different arrangements are there of all letters in "balloon" if either all the l's or all the o's are adjacent, but not both?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: Try counting just the case of adjacent l's or just the case of adjacent o's. What must you do if you sum these two?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Suppose the two Os are adjacent. First pick an order for A,B,OO,N. There are 5 places (the 3 gaps or either end) for the L,L. So you must pick two places and put one L in each. Can you see how many possibilities that gives in total. Now repeat for A,B,LL,N and placing the two Os in separate gaps. That gives you the same number. So the required answer is twice that number.

Answer (score 0):

We could use a little bit of counting and sets to tackle this problem.
$\hspace{1cm}$ Let $\mathbb{A}$ be the set containing **all arrangements with o's adjacent.**
$\hspace{1cm}$ Let $\mathbb{B}$ be the set containing **all arrangements with l's adjacent**.$\\$
$\hspace{2cm}$ Thus, if we take $\mathbb{A} \cup \mathbb{B}$ we get all the possibilities of o's and l's adjacent. But since we don't want
$\hspace{2cm}$ both occurring simultaneously, we subtract $\mathbb{A} \cap \mathbb{B}$ from $\mathbb{A} \cup \mathbb{B}$. Writing this expression in
$\hspace{2cm}$ a different form
$\hspace{3cm}$ $\mathbb{A} \cup \mathbb{B} - \mathbb{A} \cap \mathbb{B} = \mathbb{A} + \mathbb{B} - 2\mathbb{A} \cap \mathbb{B}$

For $\mathbb{A}$: We take (oo) as a unit when we have (oo)_ _ _ _ _
$\hspace{1cm}$ We are now left with 6 objects to arrange. This can be done in $\frac{6!}{2!}$ ways (we divide by 2! because' is a 
$\hspace{1cm}$ repetition)

For $\mathbb{B}$: We take (ll) as a unit when we have (ll)_ _ _ _ _. Again we have $\frac{6!}{2!}$

For $\mathbb{A} \cap \mathbb{B}$, we can count these possibilities.

$\hspace{3cm}$ (oo)(ll)_ _ _

$\hspace{3cm}$ (oo)_(ll) _ _

$\hspace{3cm}$ (oo)_ _(ll) _

$\hspace{3cm}$ (oo)_ _ _(ll)

We have 4 possibilities of (oo) and (ll) being **both** adjacent. There are 6 types of (oo) arrangement.

$\hspace{3cm}$ (oo)_ _ _ _ _

$\hspace{3cm}$ _ (oo) _ _ _ _

$\hspace{3cm}$ _ _ (oo) _ _ _

$\hspace{3cm}$ _ _ _ (oo) _ _

$\hspace{3cm}$ _ _ _ _ (oo) _

$\hspace{3cm}$ _ _ _ _ _ (oo)

Thus $\mathbb{A} \cap \mathbb{B = 6 \times 4 = 24}$

Putting all these values back in our original equation.
$\hspace{2cm} = 2 \times \frac{6!}{2!} - 2 \times 24$
$\hspace{2.5cm} = 720 - 48$
$\hspace{3cm} = \textbf{672}$